# Using parameters to solve differential equations in GEKKO python

Tags: python, gekko

I need to integrate over a system of differential equations in GEKKO and want to use parameters to alter a gradient.

Conceptually this works, but the output is not what I expected. I added a code snippet for a sample problem below to illustrate the problem.

The solver will integrate over a specified time horizon, in this case t = [0, 1, 2, 3]

A parameter is defined that represents the gradient at each value in time called p = [0, 1, 2, 3].

My expectation is that the gradient at t=0 is 0, at t=1 is 1 and so forth. Instead GEKKO interprets it as the gradient at t=0 is 1, at t=1 is 2 etc.

Is there a reason why GEKKO does not use the gradient information at t=0?

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

n = 3
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,n,n+1)       # [0, 1, 2 .. n]
y = m.Var(value=5)
p = m.Param(value=list(range(n+1))) # [0, 1, 2 .. n]

m.Equation(y.dt()==1*p)
m.options.IMODE=4
m.solve(disp=False)

plt.plot(m.time, y.value, '-x')
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `NODES=3` to get the desired output. The default in Gekko is `NODES=2` that is fast but not include interior calculation points for each step. Increasing the Nodes has the effect of increasing solution accuracy but also more variables to solve. For large problems with a long time horizon, improve the speed of simulation by using `IMODE=7` (sequential solution) instead of `IMODE=4` (simultaneous solution).

[image: Nodes]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

n = 3
t = np.linspace(0,n,n+1)
for nodes in [2,3]:

    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.time = t
    y = m.Var(value=5)
    p = m.Param(t)

    m.Equation(y.dt()==1*p)
    m.options.IMODE=4
    m.options.NODES=nodes
    m.solve(disp=False)
    plt.plot(m.time, y.value, '-x')

plt.legend(['NODES=2','NODES=3'])
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Using `t = np.linspace(0,n,301)` and `p = m.Param(np.floor(t))` with more time points shows that the solutions converge with either `NODES=2` or `NODES=3`.

[image: Solutions Converge]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  

n = 3
t = np.linspace(0,n,301)
for nodes in [2,3]:

    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    m.time = t
    y = m.Var(value=5)
    p = m.Param(np.floor(t))

    m.Equation(y.dt()==1*p)
    m.options.IMODE=4
    m.options.NODES=nodes
    m.solve(disp=False)
    plt.plot(m.time, y.value, '-.')

plt.legend(['NODES=2','NODES=3'])
plt.xlabel('time'); plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Additional information on `NODES` is in the [Dynamic Optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do) in the section on [Orthogonal Collocation on Finite Elements](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation).

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate response!